# Retain previous value in Fragments during Backstack

Tags: android

I have created same `Fragments` for multiple `View`, i.e, I have a `Fragment` like `TemplateController`, and at every item click of `ListView` same `Fragment` is loaded,like,

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id)
{
        switch (position) {

        case 0:
            Constant.TAG_VALUE = "Network";
            FragmentManager mFragmentManager =  getFragmentManager();
            TemplateController  mTemplateController = new TemplateController();
            //mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.idc_container, mTemplateController).commit();
            mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().addToBackStack(getTag()).add(R.id.idc_container, mTemplateController).commit();
            break;

        default:
            break;

        }

}
```

For every click of list item I set a `TAG_VALUE`. When I move on next view same Fragment is loaded. Next Screen I have a TableLayout. Now when I click any row of that TableLayout I again set TAG_VALUE.

```
rowLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (NcrPulseConstants.TAG_VALUE == "Unresolved") {
            NcrPulseConstants.TAG_VALUE = "ListATM";
            int tag = (Integer) v.getTag();
            switch (tag) {
            case 0:
                fileName = "a.txt";
                break;
            case 1:
                fileName = "b.txt";
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }

            String jsonLocation = Utility.loadStringFromAsset(
                    getActivity(), fileName);
            FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            TemplateController templateController = new TemplateController(
                    jsonLocation);
            mFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .addToBackStack(getTag())
                    .add(R.id.idc_container, templateController)
                    .commit();

        }

    }
});
```

`rowLayout` is a row of `TableLayout` and for every row different JSON is loaded.

My problem is that, when I click on particular row a view is open which is same `TemplateController`, then I move on Next screen then I back on this screen by pressing physical back button then I move on right screen, but when I click on another row then again next to next screen is opened, not the required scree, means when I click on back button then `TAG_VALUE` not change their value, then where I change the value of TAG_VALUE when I press the back button.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to clear tag from back stack when you move to back.
I mean just clear above tag from your current visible fragment tag. when you move back remove current tag from backstack then move previous fragment. got it?

Comment: No I have not clear the tag. At which place I clear tag.

Comment: in onBackPressed() method

Comment: This method is Activity not for Fragments. Please provide me some code.

Comment: @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
  
  FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
  Log.i("Count","Count="+manager.getBackStackEntryCount());
  if(manager.getBackStackEntryCount()>0){
  
   manager.popBackStack(yourtag);
   manager.beginTransaction().commit();
   
  }else{
   super.onBackPressed();
  }
  
 }

Comment: But I am working on Fragments then how I implement this method

Comment: yes but for fragment you have take atleast one Activity as container correct? put this method on it. understand?

Comment: have you used FrameLayout anyware?

Comment: Yes I used FrameLayout for loading Fragments.

Comment: then that is your Activity layout right? there are you have to add onbackpressed() method